# C program to calculate change

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program to calculate change, but it doesn't seem to work. 
I think that the problem is the owed 1/ paid 1; when I tried to print there values I got nothing (0).
Any help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
double owed, paid;
int  dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, cents, remainder, owed1, paid1;
printf("how much did the customer have to pay ?\n");
scanf("%f",&owed); 
printf("how much did the customer pay ?\n");
scanf("%f",&paid); 
owed1 = owed * 100;  
paid1 = paid * 100;
int change = paid1 - owed1;
dollars =  change / 100;
remainder = change % 100;
quarters = remainder / 25;
remainder = remainder % 25;
dimes = remainder / 10;
remainder = remainder % 10;
nickels = remainder / 5;
remainder = remainder % 5;
cents = remainder;
printf("%d",dollars);
printf("Dollars:%d, Quarters:%d, Dimes:%d, Nickels:%d, Cents:%d", dollars , quarters , dimes , nickels , cents );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `%f` in your scanf, which is the format specifier for a float, but your variables are doubles. You should use `%lf` instead:

```
scanf("%lf",&owed);
```

Same thing for `paid`. You should be getting warning from your compiler about that.